# Find a point on a line that is also the third vertex of a triangle

Tags: geometry

I am interested in finding the $(x, y)$ coordinates for the point, $C$ in the figure below, which is also on the line showing going through the points, $B$ and $C$. I believe this problem has a unique solution, but how can I solve it? How can I find the coordinates for point C? A step by step solution showing how I can arrive at the solution for this specific example, would be most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I feel the figure is wrong !! Because a triangle with sides 3, 4 and 5 is ought to be a right angled triangle !!!

Comment: I need way more help than I thought! It should be fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has in fact two solutions.

The distance between two points $P_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2 = (x_2,y_2)$ is given by the formula:

$$d(P_2,P_1) = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$$

So if $C = (x,y)$ we want:

$$d(C,A) = \sqrt{ (x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 } = 5 \Longrightarrow x^2 + y^2 = 25 \tag{1}$$

$$d(C,B) = \sqrt{ (x-3)^2 + (y-0)^2 } = 4 \Longrightarrow x^2 -6x + 9 + y^2 = 16 \tag {2}$$

Substract $(2)$ from $(1)$ and we get:

$6x-9 = 25 - 16 = 9 \Rightarrow 6x = 18 \Rightarrow x = 3$.

So from $(1)$ we have $3^2 + y^2 = 25 \Rightarrow y^2 = 25 - 9 = 16 \Rightarrow y = \pm 4$.

So there are two possible coordinates for $C$. Namely:

$$C_1 = (3,4) \hspace{2cm} C_2 = (3,-4)$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider the arrangement, we have one new point $D$ which is intersection of extension of $AB$ and perpendicular dropped from $C$.

Apply Pythagoras theorem once for $\triangle ADC$ and once for $\triangle BDC$

Hyp. squared=sum of squares of two sides

Find $x$, find $y$

$$C=(3+x, y)$$

Comment: You will get 2 equations in x and y, substitute x^2+y^2 from one into another